# Swift 4.2 Setter Getter, All paths through this function will call itself

Tags: swift, variables, setter, getter

With swift 4.2 I have begun to see a lot of issues, and one of them i'm not really sure how to resolve, since my getter method should be returning the value itself.

I imagine what is happening is that the getter will attempt to access the getter when calling self.type

How can i resolve this issue?

Here is a screenshot of the code with the error.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Here is the written code

```
@objc var type: DecisionType {
    set {
        if(newValue == DecisionType.DecisionDouble){
            //Yes button and NO button should be showing
            okButton.isHidden = true;
            yesButton.isHidden = false;
            noButton.isHidden = false;
        }
        else {
            //Only Ok button should be showing
            okButton.isHidden = false;
            yesButton.isHidden = true;
            noButton.isHidden = true;
        }
    }
    get {
        return self.type;
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix the return of self.type ?

Comment: @TravisDelly Has your question been answered?

Comment: ye i used didSet rather than a getter and setter.

Comment: @TravisDelly Then please mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @Alexander gotchu, sorry took me so long! Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your issue is that there is no stored property `type` for the getter to return. `type` is a computed property. When you try to read its value, it calls the getter you defined. This getter calls the getter, which in turn calls the getter which calls the getter... and so on. You have infinite recursion.

Most likely, what you meant to do is have a stored property, that just has some fancy behaviour whenever its set. Rather than using a computed property with a custom `get` and `set`, use a stored property with a `willSet` or `didSet` block:

```
@objc var type: DecisionType {
    didSet {
        let isDecisionDouble = newValue == DecisionType.DecisionDouble

        okButton.isHidden = isDecisionDouble;
        yesButton.isHidden = !isDecisionDouble;
        noButton.isHidden = !isDecisionDouble;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

A better approach for this case if to have one extra property which you will use it in return value for getter and you set it when your main property change. 
For instance let say your main property which you use is `type` then have an extra property `_type` note the **underscore** next to it. 
Then here is how you would set and retrieve your and set your main property `type`

```
// This is a an extra property which you will use internally
private var _type: DecisionType?

// Then use it as shown below
var type:DecisionType? {
get {
return _type
}

set {
  _type = newValue
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had get/set in the parent protocol extension rather than the protocol extension of the actual protocol:

```
protocol MainProtocol: SubProtocol {
   var mainVariable: String { get set } 
}

protocol SubProtocol {
    var subVariable: String { get set } 
}

extension MainProtocol {
    var mainVariable { get { return self.mainVariable } set { self.mainVariable = newValue } }

    //I KEPT MY VARIABLE HERE.  
    var subVariable { get { return self.subVariable } set { self.subVariable = newValue } }
}

extension SubProtocol {
    //THIS IS WHERE THE VARIABLE SHOULD HAVE BEEN
}
```